# Derivative of a logarithmic function

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve of $y = \ln(x² − 6x + 1)$ at the point $(6,0)$.

I've only been able to get to this point so far: $y' = \frac{1}{(x^2-6x+1)}$.

Comment: Remember the chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx} ln(f(x))$ = $\frac{1}{f(x)}*\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

That 9 is actually supposed to be a (?

Your derivative is incorrect. You have to apply the chain rule. The derivative of $(\ln\circ f)(x)$ is $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ .

Comment: Right the 9 is supposed to be a (! Can you solve the problem for me and explain each step? This is the one I'm really confused on.

Answer (score 0):

To find the derivative of logarithmic functions you have to apply the *chain rule*. This means that you have to first find the derivative of the logarithmic function to begin with, **but** you also have to find the derivative of the inner-function. For logarithms, the inner function is the $f(x)$ in $\ln \left(f(x)\right)$ or simply the bracketed expression. So for your function $y'$ is:
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx}\ln(x^2-6x+1)=\frac{1}{x^2-6x+1}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2-6x+1\right)$$
This simplifies to

> $$y'=\frac{2x-6}{x^2-6x+1}$$

To find the equation of the tangent line, you have the point at which the tangent passes through, $(6,0)$ and also the gradient of the line (plug $x=6$ into $y'$ to find the gradient, $m$). And then you'll have everything you need to find the equation of the tangent line.

**Hint:** Use $y=mx+c$, $(6,0)\implies x=6$ and $y=0$ and $m=...$